# What Happens if I Manifest a Double-Faced Card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

If I put a double-faced card onto the battlefield with Manifest (*Put it onto the battlefield face down as a 2/2 creature. Turn it face up any time for its mana cost if it’s a creature card*), what happens?  Does it enter the battlefield transformed, is it a 2/2 with no abilities, or is it not even possible to be manifested?

Comment: If the answer has done a good enough job please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This article](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rulestips/2015/01/manifest-and-double-faced-cards/) explains that double-faced cards can be manifested and enter as 2/2's with no abilities.  The actual implementation of this stems from the fact that the double-faced card must already be unidentifiable in your hand and library.  As a result, you already have the card in an opaque sleeve or you have a checklist card in your deck as a placeholder, and either of these can be put on the battlefield face-down as a state distinct from transformed.

It should be noted that double-faced cards can't be turned face down if they are already a face up permanent (such as by [Ixidron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIxidron%5d)).  The relevant rules are the following:

> 711.9. If an effect allows a player to cast a double-faced card as a face-down creature spell, or if a double-faced card enters the
>   battlefield face down, it will have the characteristics given to it by
>   the rule or effect that caused it to be face down. That card remains
>   hidden, using either a face-down checklist card or opaque sleeves. See
>   rule 707, “Face-Down Spells and Permanents.”
>
> 711.9a While face down, a double-faced permanent can’t transform. If it is turned face up, it will have its front face up.
>
> 711.10. Double-faced permanents can’t be turned face down. If a spell or ability tries to turn a double-faced permanent face down, nothing
>   happens.